# How to Split string values with some special characters in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column, `Description`, which contains string values. I want to split into 2 columns on certain special characters to generate the following 2 columns:

**1: Test/ Elegant Conditions**

**2: TASK100: Elegant Item**

expected output for below sample data should be for column1 and column2

```
Column1                             
----------------                                                
Individual/ Team Actions               
Individual/ Team Actions              
Task/ Environmental Conditions         
Task/ Environmental Conditions         
Task/ Environmental Conditions

Column2
---------
NULL

NULL

TW08: Equipment Integrity

TW01: Task Planning/ Preparation/ Manning

TW03: Work Procedures - Availability and Suitability
```

**Sample Data:**

```
CREATE TABLE [Test]
(
    [Description] [varchar](250) NULL
)
insert into [Test] values
    ('Individual/ Team Actions\|2018.04.11 00:01:37\|N');
insert into [Test] values
    ('Individual/ Team Actions\|2018.04.11 00:01:37\|N');
insert into [Test] values
    ('Task/ Environmental Conditions : TW08: Equipment Integrity\|2018.04.11 00:01:37\|N');
insert into [Test] values
    ('Task/ Environmental Conditions : TW01: Task Planning/ Preparation/ Manning\|2018.04.11 00:01:37\|N');
insert into [Test] values
    ('Task/ Environmental Conditions : TW03: Work Procedures - Availability and Suitability\|2018.04.11 00:01:37\|N');
```

I used the below sample query:

```
declare @a varchar(300)
select @a = 'Individual/ Team Actions\|2018.04.11 00:01:37\|N'
select @a C1,
    ltrim(rtrim(left(@a, charindex(':', @a)-1))) C2,
    ltrim(rtrim(substring(@a,
                          charindex(':', @a)+1,
                          charindex('\', @a)-(charindex(':', @a)+1) ))) C3
```

but got the following error:

```
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.
```

Comment: pls add expected output

Comment: to achieve your goal you cannot use a master query, because your data don't follow the same structure. I mean, the initial separator for 2 first records is '\', however, for the other ones, it's ' : '. This means that you must hardcode in your query what to do depending the type of manipulation you are doing, that's why it's being complicated for you resolve this query.

Answer (score 1):

Try that:

```
SELECT
case when charindex(' : ', description) = 0 then SUBSTRING(Description, 0, CHARINDEX('\|', Description)) else SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(Description, 0, CHARINDEX('\|', Description)), 0, charindex(' : ', description)) end,
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' : ', Description) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE SUBSTRING(Description, CHARINDEX(' : ', Description) + 3,  CHARINDEX('\|', Description) - CHARINDEX(' : ', Description) - 3) END
FROM Test
```

That returns:

```
Individual/ Team Actions       | NULL
Individual/ Team Actions       | NULL
Task/ Environmental Conditions | TW08: Equipment Integrity
Task/ Environmental Conditions | TW01: Task Planning/ Preparation/ Manning
Task/ Environmental Conditions | TW03: Work Procedures - Availability and Suitability
```

Comment: I think is not that easy and he wants to remove always the \I... part

Comment: @Bruno Miquelin                                                                                                  For second column output should be like                                                       NULL

NULL

TW08: Equipment Integrity

TW01: Task Planning/ Preparation/ Manning

TW03: Work Procedures - Availability and Suitability



**Take value before first '\'**

Comment: You are right, I missunderstood the desired return. I've edited my entire answer